# NuxtJs vue-flip not flipping between front and back sides

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I do install [vue-flip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-flip) into a NuxtJs (VueJS) project created using this command: `npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`.

In the index.vue file i just add:

```
<vue-flip active-click="true">
    <div slot="front">
      front
    </div>
    <div slot="back">
      back
    </div>
</vue-flip>
```

I do register the plugin at nuxt.config.js :

```
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vue-flip'
  ]
```

And create the file vue-flip.js at the plugins folder :

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueFlip from 'vue-flip'

Vue.use(VueFlip)
```

After run npm run dev and at localhost:3000 the text front and back are visible instead of showing just the front text so when clicking the back text would appear.

How can i fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checked you console for errors? Because there should be ones..

According to docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-flip is not a vue plugin but a component, so it wont work like this. You need to specify it as a component where you use it.

```
import VueFlip from 'vue-flip';
export default {
  components: {
    'vue-flip': VueFlip
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Aldarund, now it is working! As i am new to VueJs i can not see still, what concepts must i look to make things work. Thank´s for your help